# Add line between Google Maps points

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have two points may have different lengths. Among them is a line. I need Take the value between these 2 points. And then later add a line of another color on top . But this line should be between 1 and 1000 meters, according to user choice and according to the size of 2 points. If they are higher than 1000 meters, I add a line with or less size. How to do it with Google Maps ?

```
var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    {lat: marker.getPosition().lat(), lng: marker.getPosition().lng()},
    {lat: satelite.getPosition().lat(), lng: satelite.getPosition().lng()}
];
var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF9800',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 4
});

flightPath.setMap(map);
```

Ex:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What did wanted it can be solved with the interpolate function. Just calculate the distance between 2 points and get the percentage of the film you want and put on interpolate .

```
 google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate(Point1, Point2, 10%);
```

[Interpolate()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry?#Navigation)

Answer (score -1):

Calculating the distance between two points is really easy with the help of the Geometry library. All you have to do is to call the computeDistanceBetween() function and pass it two LatLng objects.

```
 var point1 = new google.maps.LatLng(marker.getPosition().lat(), marker.getPosition().lng());
 var point2 = new google.maps.LatLng(satelite.getPosition().lat(), satelite.getPosition().lng());
 var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(point1, point2);

 alert('distance is '+distance+'m');
```

Comment: I left with an example image, with what I want to accomplish.